# Convert hex char[] to int[] in C 2 chars in 1 byte

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I am trying to convert a char[] in hexadecimal format to int[] in hexadecimal.

Something like this:

hello --> 68656C6C6F --> [68, 65, 6C, 6C, 6F]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t* hex_decode(unsigned char *in, size_t len, uint8_t *out);

int main(void){
unsigned char  word_in[17], word_out[33];//17:16+1, 33:16*2+1
int i, len = 0;
uint8_t* out;


while(len != 16){
    printf("Set new word:");
    fgets( word_in, sizeof( word_in), stdin);
    len = strlen( word_in);
    if( word_in[len-1]=='\n')
        word_in[--len] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i<len; i++){
        sprintf(word_out+i*2, "%02X",  word_in[i]);
    }
    if(len != 16){
        printf("Please, use a word of 16 chars long\n\n");
    }
}
printf("%s", word_in);
printf("\n");

hex_decode(word_out, sizeof(word_out), out);

return 0;
}

uint8_t* hex_decode(unsigned char *in, size_t len, uint8_t *out)
{
    unsigned int i, t, hn, ln;

    for (t = 0,i = 0; i < len; i+=2,++t) {

            hn = in[i] > '9' ? (in[i]|32) - 'a' + 10 : in[i] - '0';
            ln = in[i+1] > '9' ? (in[i+1]|32) - 'a' + 10 : in[i+1] - '0';

            out[t] = (hn << 4 ) | ln;
            printf("%s",out[t]);
    }
    return out;

}
```

But after printing the word, I got a segmentation fault.

That function works perfect in arduino so I think it should works fine at my computer... Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @dasblinkenlight answer for seg fault. To decode 2 bytes:

My 50 **C**ent... (a short version)

```
char hex[3];
char * phex;
int result;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    sprintf(hex, "%02X", i);
    phex = hex;
    result = ((*phex > 64 ? (*phex & 0x7) + 9 : *phex - 48) << 4) | (*(phex+1) > 64 ? (*(phex+1) & 0x7) + 9 : *(phex+1) - 48);
    if(result != i)
    {
        printf("err %s %02X\n", hex, result);
    }
}
```

Code above does no validation. This procedure returns -1 when input was invalid.

```
int h2i(char * ph)
{
    int result;
    if(*ph > 96 && *ph < 103) result = *ph - 87;
    else if(*ph > 64 && *ph < 71) result = *ph - 55;
    else if(*ph > 47 && *ph < 59) result = *ph - 48;
    else return -1;
    result <<= 4;
    ph++;
    if(*ph > 96 && *ph < 103) result |= *ph - 87;
    else if(*ph > 64 && *ph < 71) result |= *ph - 55;
    else if(*ph > 47 && *ph < 59) result |= *ph - 48;
    else return -1;
    return result;
}
```

But wait? A char can also be -1. Yes, after casting.

```
char * x = "FF";
char y;
int result;
result = h2i(x);
// if (result == -1) ...error...
y = (char)result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a segmentation fault because you are passing the pointer `out` before making any assignments to it. Either the `hex_decode` need to take `uint8_t **out_ptr` and assign it a dynamically allocated array, or the caller needs to provide an array sufficient to hold the output of the conversion.

The reason why it "works" on another platform is that it exhibits *undefined behavior*: in arduino, the arbitrary value placed in the uninitialized pointer `out` happens to point to an unused location in memory. Writing to that location does not trigger segmentation fault, creating an illusion of working code.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks complicated comparing what you want to do.

if you want to  print the hexadecimal ascii code of a charachter, you can simply use

```
printf("%02X",'K'); // this will display the code ascii of 'K' in hexadecimal
```

If you want to print your word in code ascii in another char array. you can use `sprintf()`:

```
int main() {
        char word_in[17]="hello", word_out[33];
        char *pi = word_in, *po = word_out;
        word_out[0]=0;

        for (;*pi;po+=2,pi++)
           sprintf(po,"%02X",*pi);

        printf("%s\n", word_out);
}
```

A charachetr is saved in binary format in the memory. this binary format represent the code ascii of the charachter. And when you want to print its content:

- when using `"%d"`: this will print the code ascii as integer
- when using `"%x"`: this will print the code ascii as hexadecimal
- when using `"%c"`: this will print the charachter

Comment: I don't need to print it, I need to save it to an numerical (int, uint8_t...) array to pass as argument to other function. But thanks, mybe I can use part of it.

Comment: @Biribu the char is already saved in numerical format. the numerical format  represent its code ascii. so you can use the origin char array directly as numerical and pass it as argument to other function. No need for conversion. you can read the origin array as hexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

i will just share my own code for this:

it converts any 8 hexadecimal char string into a integer number from [-2147483648. 2147483647]
**input(argument) is 1 string(8+'\0'), output(returns) is a long int, MODIFY AS NECESSARY**

`#define N 8`

```
long int hex2dec(char* hex){        /*conversor HEX 2 DEC*/
    int i,j,n[N],l,neg;
    long int dec=0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        n[i]=0;
    }
    l=strlen(hex);

    neg=0;
    if(hex[0]>='8'){
        neg=1;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(hex[i]=='0'){
                hex[i]='F';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='1'){
                hex[i]='E';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='2'){
                hex[i]='D';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='3'){
                hex[i]='C';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='4'){
                hex[i]='B';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='5'){
                hex[i]='A';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='6'){
                hex[i]='9';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='7'){
                hex[i]='8';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='8'){
                hex[i]='7';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='9'){
                hex[i]='6';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='A'){
                hex[i]='5';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='B'){
                hex[i]='4';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='C'){
                hex[i]='3';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='D'){
                hex[i]='2';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='E'){
                hex[i]='1';
                continue;
            }
            if(hex[i]=='F'){
                hex[i]='0';
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        switch(hex[i]){
        case '0':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;  /* Ascii '0'=48 48-48=0*/
            break;
        case '1':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;  /* Ascii '1'=49 49-48=1*/
            break;
        case '2':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '3':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '4':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '5':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '6':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '7':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '8':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case '9':
            n[i]=hex[i]-48;
            break;
        case 'A':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;  /* Ascii 'A'=65 65-55=10*/
            break;
        case 'B':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;  /* Ascii 'B'=66 66-55=11*/
            break;
        case 'C':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;
            break;
        case 'D':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;
            break;
        case 'E':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;
            break;
        case 'F':
            n[i]=hex[i]-55;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0,j=l;i<l;i++,j--){
        dec=dec+(n[j-1]*pow(16,i));
    }
    if(neg==1){
        dec=0-dec;
        dec=dec-1;
    }
    return dec;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have converted the string to hex. I just need how to join 2 chars in one to make the hex number: "1\0" -> "31\0" ->31(int) <-this is what I need.

Comment: Ever heard of a `switch` statement?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
uint8_t *out;//region is not ensured
```

to

```
uint8_t out[sizeof(word_out)/2];
```

change

```
hex_decode(word_out, sizeof(word_out), out);//sizeof(word_out) is 33, must to 32
```

to

```
hex_decode(word_out, strlen(word_out), out);//strlen(word_out) or len * 2 or sizeof(word_out) -1
```

change

```
printf("%s",out[t]);//out is not string
```

to

```
printf("%02X ",out[t]);
```